# Svn and reviewboard

Tags: svn, review-board

I would like to setup svn to be able to send diff to reviewboard like 'hg postreview' plugin does. Can anybody suggest such plugin for SVN ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look to the [post-review](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.5/users/tools/post-review/#post-review) tool from reviewboard, it should help you to post review from an svn local copy.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin for Visual Studio called IronBoard which may do just what you want. Search in Visual Studio gallery.